# ERROR: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Error:

```
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'substring')
    at typewriter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:681:58)
```

Code:

```
const speed = 50
let textPosition = 0
function typewriter(event) {
    const message = event;
    document.querySelector("#message").innerHTML = message.substring(0, textPosition) + '<span>\u2758</span>'
  
    if(textPosition++ !== message.length)
        setTimeout(typewriter, speed)
}

window.onload = function(){
    typewriter(`Test`)
}
```

Can someone please help me because I'm kind of stuck

I wanted an h1 which is like a write effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function typewriter requires a parameter which isn't provided when called by setTimeout.  You can wrap the typewriter function in an anonymous function which provides it.

```js
const speed = 50
let textPosition = 0
function typewriter(message) {
    document.querySelector("#message").innerHTML = message.substring(0, textPosition) + '<span>\u2758</span>'
  
    if(textPosition++ !== message.length)
        setTimeout(() => typewriter(message), speed)
}

window.onload = function(){
    typewriter(`Test`)
}
```

```html
<div id="message"></div>
```